# Auto refresh ListView with Image and Text using Volley Json Mysql

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I made a few years ago a android radio app (api 8) that plays a online radiostation and displays the info that comes from a mysql database
I used xml to show the info on the Text and ImageView and updated the data with a timer

Now I want to update my app to api 15 after being offline for a while but the saxparser dont work no more on api 15 so I followed a tutorial and updated my app with  a listview json and a customlistadapter

Only now I dont know how to auto refresh the "now playing" info.
I tried many things searched many tutorials but I still cant figure out  how to achieve this with my new code.

This was my old code which worked with saxparser:

```
private class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.example.com/linktodata.php");
                XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
                xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                data = XMLHandler.data;

                for (int i = 0; i < data.getTitle().size(); i++) {
                    Lyrics.setText(data.getLyric().get(i));
                    myimageURL = data.getPic().get(i);

                    Song.setText(data.getTitle().get(i));
                    Song.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7cfc00"));

                    frAlbum.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#cd853f"));

                    Artist.setText(data.getArtist().get(i));
                    Artist.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                    Album.setText(data.getAlbum().get(i));
                    Album.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

                    nowplaying.setText("Now Playing...");
                    nowplaying.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#cd853f"));
                }
                downloadFile(myimageURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Bitmap bmImg;

        void downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
            URL myFileUrl = null;
            try {
                myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                if (bmImg != null) {
                    AlbumPic.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                    AlbumPic.clearAnimation();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_updateTime, DELAY);
            // timer end
        }
    }
```

This is what I have now 
My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";

    static public SeekBar sb;
    public static ToggleButton playStop;

     static TextView  tvBuffer;

    // Music json url
    private static final String url = "http://www.example.com/linktodata.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<Music> ();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    private UpdateTimeTask m_updateTime;
    private Handler m_handler;
    public AudioManager am;
    /**
     * The delay in milliseconds between updates.
     */
    private final int DELAY = 3000;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

        listView = (ListView) findViewById ( R.id.list );
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter ( this, musicList );
        listView.setAdapter ( adapter );

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog ( this );
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage ( "Loading..." );
        pDialog.show ();
        tvBuffer = findViewById ( R.id.tvBuffer );


        playStop = findViewById ( R.id.toggPlayStop );
        playStop.setBackgroundResource ( R.drawable.stopbtn );
        sb = findViewById ( R.id.volumCntrl );


        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService ( Context.AUDIO_SERVICE );

        int maxV = am.getStreamMaxVolume ( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );
        int curV = am.getStreamVolume ( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );
        sb.setMax ( maxV );
        sb.setProgress ( curV );

        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener ( this );
        playStop.setOnClickListener ( this );
        tvBuffer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvBuffer.setTextColor( Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

// changing action bar color


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest musicReq = new JsonArrayRequest ( url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d ( TAG, response.toString () );
                        hidePDialog ();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length (); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject ( i );
                                Music music = new Music ();
                                music.setTitle ( obj.getString ( "title" ) );
                                music.setThumbnailUrl ( obj.getString ( "picture" ) );
                                music.setAlbum ( obj.getString ( "album" ) );
                                music.setLyrics ( obj.getString ( "lyrics" ) );
                                music.setArtist ( obj.getString ( "artist" ) );


                                // adding music to music array
                                musicList.add ( music );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener () {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d ( TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage () );
                hidePDialog ();

            }
        } );        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(musicReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart ();
        try {
            if (UtilityClass.isInternetOn ( this )) {
                m_updateTime = new UpdateTimeTask ();
                m_handler = new Handler ();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        playStop.setChecked ( false );


    }   private class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }m_handler.post ( m_updateTime );
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume ();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
        new PlayerStatusCheck ().execute ();
    }

    //AsyncTask Class
    class PlayerStatusCheck extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
        boolean isServiceAvailable;

        private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService ( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                    .getRunningServices ( Integer.MAX_VALUE )) {
                if (com.example.my.My_Service.class.getName ()
                        .equals ( service.service.getClassName () )) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            isServiceAvailable = isMyServiceRunning ();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if ((isServiceAvailable)) {
                playStop.setChecked ( true );
                playStop.setBackgroundResource ( R.drawable.stopbtn );
                tvBuffer.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                if (My_Service.mediaPlayer.isPlaying ()) {
                    playStop.setBackgroundResource ( R.drawable.playbtn );

                }


            } else {
                playStop.setChecked ( false );


            }


        }
    }






    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        am.setStreamVolume ( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0 );
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (playStop.isChecked() && UtilityClass.isInternetOn(this)) {
            tvBuffer.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);

            playStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbtn);


            startService(new Intent (this, My_Service.class));

        } else if (UtilityClass.isInternetOn(this)) {
            stopService(new Intent(this, My_Service.class));
            playStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbtn);



        }

    }

}
```

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      TextView title;
    TextView album;
    TextView artist;
    TextView lyrics;
    NetworkImageView thumbNail;


    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Music> musicItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Music> musicItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.musicItems = musicItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return musicItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return musicItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        thumbNail = convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        album = convertView.findViewById(R.id.album);

        artist = convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        lyrics = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lyrics);

        // getting music data for the row
        Music m = musicItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl("https://example.com/album_art/" + m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        album.setText(String.valueOf(m.getAlbum ()));

        // genre
    artist.setText ( m.getArtist () );

        // release year
        lyrics.setText((m.getLyrics ()));

        return   convertView;
    }

}
```

Music object Data:

```
public class Music {
    private String title;
    private String lyrics;
    private String album;
    private String artist;
    private String thumbnailUrl;


    public Music() {
    }

    public Music(String title, String thumbnailUrl, String lyrics, String album, String artist)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.lyrics = lyrics;
        this.album = album;
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public String getLyrics() {
        return lyrics;
    }

    public void setLyrics(String lyrics) {
        this.lyrics = lyrics;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist (String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

}
```

- [credits to the Tutorial that I followed to show the data in listview:](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

I hope someone can help me out.
It is the last step to finish the app.

Comment: have you tried  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by this way.
 
Take on `boolean` in your `Music` class to do the stuff. Assign it `true` when you play them and all other will become `false`.

Now check that `boolean` in your `CustomListAdapter` Adapter class.
If it's true then show your `Now Playing` info text else hide it.

**Don't forgot to make all other `boolean` to `false` when you assign `true` to the particular one and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after it.**

So your code looks like this...

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...

        // getting music data for the row
        Music m = musicItems.get(position);

        ...

        if(m.getIsPlaying())
           -show playNow text.
        else
           -hide it.

        ...

        return   convertView;
    }

}
```

Music object class looks like this.

```
public class Music {
    ...
    private boolean isPlaying;

    public Music() {
    }

    public Music(String title, String thumbnailUrl, String lyrics, String album, String artist, boolean isPlaying)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.lyrics = lyrics;
        this.album = album;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.isPlaying = isPlaying.
    }

    ...

    public String getIsPlaying() {
        return isPlaying;
    }

    public void setIsPlaying(boolean isPlaying) {
        this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and help. I will check the code tonight and let you know

Comment: I still cant get it to refresh the data. maybe I am doing something wrong. What do you mean by "Don't forgot to make all other boolean to false when you assign true to the particular one and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after it." Where exactly should this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() be?

Comment: when you play specific item at that time make that music object isPlaying = true and make all other to false. Then after call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Should I put the call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the MainActivity?

Comment: where you create your adapter object there you should do that. Or you should do that from where you playing your track.